# How to link mulitple css&js files in our project without explicity mentioning it in every other file

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4, html2canvas

My project is on angularjs and php. I have been placed in a project that has been previously done by a group of 3 and the documentation was not clear. What I observe from that code is that whenever I declare any bootstrap class or id 
without explicitly linking it in that html file

Eg:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>some title</title>
<!-- No CSS file linked here -->
</head>
<body>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Here</button>
</body>
```

For above document bootstrap classes "btn btn-primary" are applied. However, they have included that bootstrap file in a folder named "css" but DID NOT include/import that in that html file.

How does my html file know where to search for suitable css file?
Does it search all the available css files?
Is that a good practice or do I need to change that?

when I go to inspect -> sources

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="quiz">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/displayController.js"></script>
     <script src="controllers/quizController.js"></script>
     <script src="controllers/welcomeController.js"></script> 
    <script src="controllers/csvController.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/loginController.js"></script>
     <script src="controllers/adminController.js"></script>
    <style>
    body
        {    
   background-color: bisque;

   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
} 
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-view>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the default html for every page, now if I add anyother .js(In js file) or .css( In css file) it doesn't show up here or adds in my html. This came to notice when I added HTML2CANVAS file for one particular html file and it is saying "html2canvas is not defined" in console

**Edit:**

Thanks for the help `JkAlombro`, I found that this project uses angular router(`$routeprovider`) So I traced default html file(index.html in this case) and added my js scripts and css links. To know whether your project uses `$routeprovider`, goto app.js file and check for `app.config(function($routeProvider)`. Just so it helps anyone.

Comment: Does the project use some kind of router? like `$routeProvider`, etc? Because you don't need to import css file to every html if you have that

Comment: It might be using some task runner like gulp or grunt or webpack. That compile and modify your HTML file and add css files on runtime.

Comment: where/what is ng-app?

Comment: There is no $routeprovider in any of the "controllers" file.

Comment: I don't see any task runner in my project, even if it is how to identify them?

Comment: Does adding ng_app and ng-controller import those files?

Comment: @Nikhil1109 actually, you're indeed using a router based on the index.html you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't see any css/js imports to your other HTML files is because that app using an angular router (most probably `$routeProvider`) and I can confirm that in your index html file.

See that `<div ng-view>` in your index? That's where all of your other html files are being displayed depending on what route is being pointed. Other proofs that you are using angular router is this script

```
<script src="script/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

**Why you don't have to import your css and js in the rest of your html file?**

Because everything is being rendered to your index.html (or whatever your default html file is named) so you only need to include all of your scripts and css links there and it will be used all over your app. That's how a Single Page Application works (at least for AngularJS).

If you wanna trace where the router is being configured, most probably you can find it in your `app.js` or `displayController.js`.

Comment: What do you mean by changed it to required?

Comment: And btw, as I've mentioned, it seems that the app is using an angular router. Apps with router works differently with traditional html websites so if you haven't used it or known it yet, try reading it on angularjs documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Make a common header and footer file. Include all your css file in header and javaScript file in footer.

eg:
header.file
 - Only push your content here -
footer.file

- This way the css and js will be common for every other file.

Comment: that's a great procedure but it uses angular router and I'm not familiar about it, Hence this is all new for me.

Comment: Actually the process I told is common to all the frameworks, the only thing you have to write the code according to language you are using.